# FXML Variables not binding

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am having an issue with my FXML injection.  I have setup my program as far as I can tell but it seems that I am missing something. My code is below:

Main:

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("NoteKeeper.fxml"));

            BorderPane root = (BorderPane)loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,root.getHeight(),root.getWidth());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
package application;




import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class NoteKeeperController implements Initializable{
    NoteBook noteBook;
    TreeItem<String> rootItem;

    public BorderPane root;

    @FXML private TreeView<String> noteTree;

    @FXML private ScrollPane sp;
    @FXML private Button newNoteButton;
    public NoteKeeperController(){

        rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("FirstNote");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);     
        noteTree.setRoot(rootItem);

        noteBook= new NoteBook();

    }
    @FXML
    private void closeProgram(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @FXML
    private void addNewNote(){
        Note note = noteBook.newNote("test", "Problem");
        TreeItem<String> newItem= new TreeItem<>(note.getNoteName());
        rootItem.getChildren().add(newItem);
    }

    public BorderPane getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public void setRoot(BorderPane root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

FXML File:

```
<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="719.0" prefWidth="893.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="application.NoteKeeperController">
   <center>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="641.0" prefWidth="872.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <center>
            <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <tabs>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
                  <content>
                    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                  </content>
                </Tab>
              </tabs>
            </TabPane>
         </center>
         <left>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="sp" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TreeView fx:id="noteTree" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                     </children>
```

`Scenebuilder` recognizes the fields that I'm injecting *noteTree, sp , and newNoteButton*.  However when testing I am getting a NPE when I try to load items to my treeview.  I confirmed using if statements that my 3 fields are `null`.  The stack trace is below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.NoteKeeperController.<init>(NoteKeeperController.java:31)
```

Also as it turns out my `@FXML closeProgram()` and my `@FXML addNewNote()` functions are being passed ok.

Can anyone point out what I am missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to set the root item of the tree view in the controller's constructor.

When the `FXMLLoader` loads the fxml file, it will parse the fxml file, noting any `fx:id` attributes. It will instantiate the controller (by calling it's no-arg constructor), and then it will initialize any `@FXML`-annotated fields with the corresponding objects with matching `fx:id` attributes. When that is done, it calls the controller's `initialize()` method, if there is one.

So your constructor is executed before the `noteTree` is initialized by the `FXMLLoader` (and of course, this is the only order in which things could possibly happen). Hence when you call

```
    noteTree.setRoot(rootItem);
```

`noteTree` is still `null`.

The fix is simply to move the code in the constructor to the `initialize` method:

```
public class NoteKeeperController implements Initializable{
    NoteBook noteBook;
    TreeItem<String> rootItem;

    public BorderPane root;

    @FXML private TreeView<String> noteTree;

    @FXML private ScrollPane sp;
    @FXML private Button newNoteButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){

        rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("FirstNote");
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);     
        noteTree.setRoot(rootItem);

        noteBook= new NoteBook();

    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it cant believe I've been banging my head into a wall trying to figure this out.  Thank You!