# BorderPane always return null value

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am dealing with JavaFX , I am trying to get my graphical composant from my FXML page into the java classes, but it always return null value

Page.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<ScrollPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <content>
        <BorderPane maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308"  fx:id="Mycontent">
            <top>
                <fx:include source="TopMenu.fxml" />
            </top>
         <center>
                <fx:include source="Operation.fxml" />
         </center>
         <left>
             <fx:include source="SideBar_Inhumer.fxml" />
         </left>
         <bottom>
             <fx:include source="Footer.fxml" />
         </bottom>
        </BorderPane>
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public BorderPane Mycontent;

    @FXML
    public void goToDemandeur(){
        System.out.println(Mycontent);

        //Mycontent.setCenter(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Demandeur.fxml")));
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }
}
```

My code always print "null"

if I try for example `Mycontent.getCenter()`it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

(which normal because Mycontent is null, but why it is null? )

PS: my method `goToDemandeur()` is called into an other fxml page `SideBar_Inhumer.fxml` after a click `onMouseClicked="#goToDemandeur"`

SideBar_Inhumer.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox layoutX="77.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
       <Pane >
           <children>
               <Label alignment="CENTER" text="Inhumer" >
                   <font>
                      <Font size="24.0" />
                   </font>
                   <padding>
                       <Insets bottom="20.0" left="25.0" right="25.0" top="30.0"  />
                   </padding>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </Pane>
       <Pane style="-fx-background-color: #F08080;" onMouseClicked="#goToDemandeur">
           <children>
               <Label text="Demandeur" >
                   <font>
                       <Font size="15.0" />
                   </font>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               </Label>

           </children>
         <VBox.margin>
            <Insets />
         </VBox.margin>
       </Pane>
       <Pane style="-fx-background-color: #C6E2B9;">
           <children>
               <Label text="Defunt">
                   <font>
                       <Font size="15.0" />
                   </font>
                   <padding>
                       <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                   </padding>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </Pane>
       <Pane style="-fx-background-color: #FBF6A5;">
           <children>
               <Label text="Emplacement">
                   <font>
                       <Font size="15.0" />
                   </font>
                   <padding>
                       <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                   </padding>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </Pane>
       <Pane style="-fx-background-color: #FFCC99;">
           <children>
               <Label text="Prestataire">
                   <font>
                       <Font size="15.0" />
                   </font>
                   <padding>
                       <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                   </padding>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </Pane>
       <Pane style="-fx-background-color: #D8B46D;">
           <children>
               <Label text="Opération">
                   <font>
                       <Font size="15.0" />
                   </font>
                   <padding>
                       <Insets bottom="10.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
                   </padding>
               </Label>
           </children>
       </Pane>

   </children>
</VBox>
```

Main.java

```
    package View;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../View/Page.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Finalys");
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
        Scene scene =new Scene(root, 600, 475);
        primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("bootstrap2.css").toExternalForm());


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show how you load Page.fxml?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FXML Variables not binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810243/fxml-variables-not-binding)

Comment: It is a good practice if you use camel case for your properties like `Mycontent`

Comment: I'm not that familiar with JavaFX but I'd assume it uses the Java Beans convention which is based on the basic Java code convention and that states that variables, fields etc. should use a name starting with a lower case character and then use camelcase. Especially the first requirement is meant to reduce confusion between class and field names, i.e. `Mycontent` looks like a class name but it isn't. Try `mycontent` or better `myContent` instead.

Comment: @Tschallacka my method goToDemandeur is called into an other fxml page `SideBar_Inhumer.fxm` after a click `onMouseClicked="#goToDemandeur"` so moving the code into `initialize()` won't help me

Comment: @Bashir You're not showing your loader code, so it's hard to see. Can you include the click handler code that initializes everything? Have you tried running this through a debugger with a breakpoint at the onclick?

Comment: @Bashir Where's your `goToDemandeur()` code?

Comment: @Tschallacka in Controller.java , it is mentionned in my question, I only print my BorderPane to see its value, when I try to edit the myContent I get Error `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` which is always mentionned in the question ))

Comment: @Bashir you said you initialize the Page.fxml in the click handler. So show us that click handler. You're not showing where you initialize the Page.fxml

Comment: @Tschallacka it is loaded in the Main.java , and in my Page.fxml , as you can see I have include tags to load other pages into my borderPane, and as you can see also , in SideBar_Inhumer.fxml you will find that I have  `onMouseClicked="#goToDemandeur" ` I think it is so clear

Comment: when I copied and pasted the code of my SideBar_Inhumer.fxml into Page.fxml it solved the problem, I mean by eliminating the include tag, but I want to seperate the code of each element and show them in the same page, my problem is that my controller is loaded in different pages which causes this problem (well I guess so, this is my first app with java fx)

Comment: yeah, the problem is indeed the same controller for different fxmls: that's not useful, because there is a new controller instance created for each loading with only those fields injected that the fxml knows about, that's why SideBar cannot inject myContent which is simply kept null. Use different controllers for different fxmls and all will work fine :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One controller to 2 fxmls (JavaFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464857/one-controller-to-2-fxmls-javafx)